# Bootstrap 3 как инициализировать toggle кнопку на панели?

Tags: bootstrap

Если эта панель была загружена динамически с помощью ajax.

К примеру чтоб работал tooltip после загрузки html кода динамически на страницу, в конце ajax завершения добавляю:

```js
     //------------- Bootstrap tooltips -------------//
    $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip({
      container: 'body'
    });
    $(".tip").tooltip({
      placement: 'top',
      container: 'body'
    });
    $(".tipR").tooltip({
      placement: 'right',
      container: 'body'
    });
    $(".tipB").tooltip({
      placement: 'bottom',
      container: 'body'
    });
    $(".tipL").tooltip({
      placement: 'left',
      container: 'body'
    });
```

Comment: не понятно... в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Когда добавляешь класс toggle. Появляется справа вверху на панели кнопка с крестиком. Нажимая на нее панель сжимается и раздвигается. Это если сразу html код прописать на странице с подключенными скриптами. А если уже страница загружена и код этой панели я подгружаю в div с помощью ajax запроса. То кнопка не появляется. Как ее инициализировать, чтоб она появилась после добавления в html, кода панели. И начала работать как требуется от нее?